# Xcode 12 and iOS 14 SDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, xcode12

Starting April 2021, all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 12 and the iOS 14 SDK.
When apple says "iOS 14 SDK", what does it means,
Do we need to update the Deployment target or some other setting we need to enable?

Comment: In addition to the great answer by @Duncan_C, I might add that "real soon now" iOS devices using 14.5 are a *huge* update (currently in beta 5!) and if you need to use Xcode 12.5 (also in beta) you'll need Big Sur (or macOS 11). This would be the second year that Apple has pretty much forced developers to upgrade their macOS version beyond the "annual" cycle the begins with WWDC. You *can* use Xcode 12.4 and Catalina (macOS 10.15) but if you want the "iOS 14.5 SDK" (or use that simulator) you'll either use a manual install of the SDK or be forced to upgrade to Big Sur.

Comment: Whew! And I thought Microsoft owned "DLL Hell", and Apple owned the "it just works" phrase. Finally, if (and when) you *do* upgrade to Big Sur, be aware that bootable backups *are* possible, but are much more challenging than in Catalina.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "iOS x SDK" means that you need to build your apps using the version of Xcode that includes support for iOS version x. (Apple releases versions of the iOS SDK as part of the Xcode IDE.) If Xcode 12 is the first version of Xcode that supports iOS 14, you need to build with Xcode 12.

I don't think the deployment target is an issue.

Comment: Hi Duncan, if a vendor deliver a build that supposed to use XCode 12, how can I find out this? (we just got the binary, not the source).